# Did Mighty Morphin Power Rangers: The Movie take place in an alternate timeline?

Tags: parallel-universe, alternate-history, mighty-morphin-power-rangers

The 1995 film **Mighty Morphin Power Rangers: The Movie** plays out like an extended special episode, giving the Rangers new "Ninjetti" powers and Zords based not around the Dinosaurs, but modern day animals. The foe they faced was Ivan Ooze, an enemy so powerful he had to be taken out by a *freaking comet!* He basically wiped out Zordon, and by extension, the Rangers original Dino powers, and they had to go all the way to the planet Pheados to essentially get them re-ignited. The new animals carried over to the next season of the show.

However.... the entirety of the film... from Ivan's presence, to the Great Power that changed their beasts.... is **never** mentioned even once. In the continuation of the series, the new Ninja powers and beasts were explained as coming from *Ninjor,* a powerful being that taught the Rangers the ways of the space ninja and helped them develop their new Zords and powers.

Does that mean the whole film "Didn't happen" in Ranger canon, or that it took place on another time line?

Complicating matters more is the current MMPR comic series; it deals with different timelines, the most notable being the *Shattered Grid* timeline in which Tommy becomes a doubly powered White/Green Ranger and destroys his team, in which *Another* version of the heroes has to stop him....it's convoluted.

Basically, did the events of the film take place at all?

Comment: Of course the events of the film took place and are canon - in the film.  So I could make that an answer "Yes the events of the 1995 film did take place at all; they took place in the 1995 film.  But I suppose that you want to know what is the relationship between the 1995 film and the television series.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Quite right, friend, that is indeed what I was asking. Hence me asking if the film was a separate timeline from the series.

Comment: " Basically, did the events of the film take place at all?" I remember watching the film so it definitely happened

Answer (score 2):

The [fandom wiki](https://powerrangers.fandom.com/wiki/Mighty_Morphin_Power_Rangers:_The_Movie) states that this is an alternate telling of events in the timeline:

> Mighty Morphin Power Rangers: The Movie was created by Saban Entertainment and released by 20th Century Fox in the summer of 1995. The movie stars the same actors from the 1994-1995 version of the Mighty Morphin Power Rangers television series, but is an alternate telling of events.

What they mean by an ["alternate telling"](https://powerrangers.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Alternate_Canon) is effectively an expansion on the existing universe.

> Alternate canon generally refer to material or media and character, contents and concepts outside the source material that takes a new spin on it and develops it for a new subfranchise.

So basically; this does happen within the same universe as the exiting Mighty Morphin Power Rangers Series. This is why the new Zords carry through to the series after the events of the movie.

Continuity in the MMPR series is never really necessary, beyond major plot points. Each episode is generally a self-contained story; once the good guys win, that story is completed.

Other examples of the "continuity" in the MMPR series are [Tommy Oliver](https://powerrangers.fandom.com/wiki/Tommy_Oliver); he starts out as the bad guy, then joins the Rangers, and is ultimately given the power of the White Ranger, to replace the loss of his Green Ranger powers. Once this happens, the Green Ranger is never really mentioned again, apart from a solo episode about a cloned Green Ranger, made by Rita Repulsa.

---

[Official wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mighty_Morphin_Power_Rangers_(season_3)) information however, states that this is *not* part of the official storyline, but does not expand on it's place in the Power Rangers Universe, alternate or otherwise (Episode 116/Season 3, Episode 4):

> This episode aired almost three months after the premiere of Mighty Morphin Power Rangers: The Movie. The plot of the saga features a similar plot to that of the movie or rather, the Ninja Quest Saga is an alternate version of how the Rangers got their Ninja Powers. Due to this, the movie was confirmed to not be part of the official Power Ranger storyline.

Comment: The wiki is a fan-written work. Can you offer any *official* evidence?